# Issue in OAF during page load

Tags: oracle, oracle-ebs, oracleapplications, oaf

Actually I want to load the `page` again because for the first time  when I am loading the page one of my `VO` is not getting initialized  (`fetchedrowcount` is coming as 0),but when we go to home and then navigate to that page again then the `rowcount` is coming as 1. Can you please help me how can I achieve this on first time page load itself. Please do reply,I am stucked badly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an ordering issue - VO is likely being queried after the page is rendered.

Have you tried querying the VO explicitly in the PageRequest() method?  The [Oracle Application Framework Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26401_01/nav/technology.htm) is a good resource if you don't know how to do that.